# Limitations of using interpolated data

Tags: descriptive-statistics, distance-functions, interpolation

I have a data set that is composed of point locations in a landscape, lets call this dataset X. Some of the points in data set X need to be grouped together because they "function" together as a single unit in space. Let's call this subset of data, set A; it has 20 points but only 6 groups. The remaining points are set B so X = {A, B}. I would like to aggregate the set A group values using an inverse distance weighted mean function to yield 6 group values that I'll call set C. From this, I would like to create a new data set composed of sets B and C and develop summary statistics for this new data set U. Can I calculate summary statistics over a data set of sampled and interpolated values with a clear statistical conscience? Am I breaking the rules? Thanks!

Comment: I lost you at "aggregate": could you explain more precisely what this amounts to and how C is supposed to be computed from A?  What kinds of summary statistics do you intend to develop and what will you use them for?  (The validity of any answers to this question depends on that information.)